# jQueryUI Multiple droppable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How come when I drag my `draggable` div to `droppable1` div it always gets placed in `droppable2` div.

In addition I followed the jQuery UI snap-back option but it does not work. How could I make it that instead of dragging the actual `draggable` element it drags an instance/copy of it and have `droppable` accept multiple of these `draggable` elements.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( '#draggable' ).draggable();

    $( '#droppable1' ).droppable({
      drop: function(event, ui)
      {
        $(this)
          .append(ui.draggable.css({position: 'relative', left: '0px', top: '0px'}));
      }
    });

    $( '#droppable2' ).droppable({
      drop: function(event, ui)
      {
        $(this)
          .append(ui.draggable.css({position: 'relative', left: '0px', top: '0px'}));
      }
    });



  });
</script>

<div class="well">
  <div id="draggable">CONTENT</div>
</div>

<div id="droppable1" class="well col-md-3" style="z-index:-1;"></div>
<div id="droppable2" class="well col-md-9" style="z-index:-1;"></div>
```

Comment: a simple reading on Jqueryui.com would help.

Comment: This is what their example states: Enable any DOM element to be droppable, a target for draggable elements. And I followed their example so no.

Comment: You want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/v3L7A/

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward How you answered all 3 of my questions there. Thanks if you put it down as answer ill accept it +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a clone [`helper`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) for the draggable option, than in the [`drop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) event clone and append the dropped helper.

Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('#draggable').draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });

    $('#droppable1, #droppable2').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .append(ui.helper.clone(false).css({
                position: 'relative',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px'
            }));
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/v3L7A/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **accept** filter to accept specific items in specifc droppable area.

```
$( '#droppable1' ).droppable({
      accept: '#draggable',
      drop: function(event, ui)
      {
        $(this)
          .append(ui.draggable.css({position: 'relative', left: '0px', top: '0px'}));
      }
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the missing accept allow any draggable element to be dropped inside ?

Comment: yes, if you are not having any accept parameter then it will allow all draggable elements,but you need to highlight the proximity dropable area to know where you are dropping.

Add **hoverClass: "Hightlight",**  and some css say .Highlight{color:red} to detect in which area you are about to drop.

Comment: I did however droppable1 never lights up