# Other droppable divs not working like the 1st one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

My 1st droppable div box is working perfectly however the rest of my droppable div boxes aren't. I've been looking through my code and couldn't figure out where the problem is.


When I drag a draggable clone element in the other divs (2,3,4) they go at the very bottom of the page and then when I click the clone it suddenly goes to the first one with out even trying to move it yet.

HELP?

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#classicTemplate").resizable();

          $(".dragImgs").draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            snap: ".dropTarget",
            appendTo: "#classicTemplate",
            revert: "invalid"
          });

          $(".dropTarget").droppable({
            accept: ".dragImgs",
            hoverClass: "highlight",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
              var $imgClone = ui.helper.clone();
              if (!$imgClone.is(".inside-dropTarget")) {
                $(this).append($imgClone.addClass("inside-dropTarget").draggable({
                  containment: ".dropTarget",
                  position: "relative"
                }));

                $imgClone.dblclick(function() {
                  $imgClone.remove();
                });
              }
            }
          }).resizable({
            animate: "true",
            ghost: "true",
            handles: "n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw, all"
          });
        });
```

```css
        .container {
          background-color: #bbb;
        }
        
        .imageContainer {
          float: left;
          margin: 10px;
          width: 230px;
          background-color: #fff;
        }
        
        .imageContainer img {
          margin: 10px;
          margin-left: 15px;
        }
        
        #classicTemplate {
          list-style-type: none;
          float: right;
          margin-top: 10px;
          background-color: #ccc;
        }
        
        #classicTemplate ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          padding: 0;
        }
        
        .dropTarget {
          background-color: #aaa;
          margin: 10px;
          width: 210px;
          height: 143px;
        }
        
        .dragImgs {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          margin: 10px;
          background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <div class="dragImgs">
    </div>

    <div class="dragImgs">
    </div>

    <div class="dragImgs">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="classicTemplate">
    <div class="dropTarget pull-left">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="dropTarget pull-left">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="dropTarget pull-left">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="dropTarget pull-left">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251597/jquerryui-multiple-droppable-elements

Comment: @im_benton I looked at the answer and implemented it on my code. I can drag a clone to the other droppable divs but when I drag the clone inside the drop target it moves to the 1st div. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doraaa/ea4ry1w0/3/

Comment: I think it has something to do with the jquery selector. Did you try using id's?  $(".dropTarget") to  $("#dropTarget1, #dropTarget2, #dropTarget3") and updating your html to have the id's?

Comment: @im_benton thanks, I did what u suggested and found a filter that works `"$("div[id^=dropTarget]").droppable();"` also I found out why it keeps on moving to the first div because of the option in the clone `containment: ".dropTarget"` and changed it to `"parent"` and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/doraaa/ea4ry1w0/4/ thank you so much